# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins : failed to deploy artifacts

Tags: java, maven, openshift

To deploy  3rd party JAR (OpenNlP) on marven remote repository I am using

> E:\PROSOL\prosol\prosol>mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=opennlp-1.5.3.jar  -DgroupId=opennlp.tools -DartifactId=opennlp -Dversion=1.5.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=eap -Durl=http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>prosol</groupId>
<artifactId>prosol</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>prosol</name>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.alpha-13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opennlp.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
        invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
        will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
        folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>prosol</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

After execution it shows 
[image]

what this error means and how can I resolve it ?

Please reply this is my final year project

Comment: You are trying to deploy artifacts to maven.repository.redhat.com which i assume will not work...so you have to change the distributionManagement in your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know why but pom file is not having distributionManagement. what should I do ? or How can I declare it ?

Comment: Take a look into the parent from which you inherit....

Comment: Actually I am new to it and don't know how to check. please explain how can i check. thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: Your own pom file contains an element `<parent>...</parent>`? Yes than take a look at this artifact...